# Why is The Parameter of a Function Retrieved From an Object "never"

Tags: json, typescript

I'd expect this code to work. But instead I get this TypeError.

The idea is that `myFunctions` holds handlers for data received from JSON.
The JSON objects are either of type A, or of type B. If `type` is "a" I want `param` to be handled by the function stored in `myFunctions`.

This is my approach, but the signature of the retrieved function is `never` allthough all type information is available.

```js
const myFunctions = {
    "a": function(o: string) {return "A"},
    "b": function(o: number) {return "B"}
};

interface A {
    type: "a"
    param: string
}
interface B {
    type: "b"
    param: number
}

function getIt(i: A | B) {
    const p = i.param;
    const f = myFunctions[i.type];
    // at this point typescript identifies the type of f to be ((o: string) => string) | ((o: number) => string)
    return f(p); // <- Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this behaviour occurs and how to fix it?

Alternatively I'd be happy to hear about other approaches to call the correct handler given a certain JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this without introducing new `if` or `switch` statements. Typescript can't really follow that `f` and `p` are related and consistent with one another. Your use case could probably be helped by something like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) proposal but that has been sitting as a proposal for a while so I would not really wait for it.

The issue here is that `i.type` is `"A" | "B"`, so when using it to index `myFunctions` you just get back a union of all functions (`((o: string) => string) | ((o: number) => string)`). But this union of functions is only callable with an argument that is an intersection of all possible arguments. That intersection here is `string & number` which typescript reduces to `never` since it is a primitive intersection that can never be inhabited by any value. You can read [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011) about the rules on union invocation.

You can add an `if` or `switch` to fix this, although it does make the code redundant:

```
function getIt(i: A | B) {
    switch (i.type) {
        case "a": return myFunctions[i.type](i.param)
        case "b": return myFunctions[i.type](i.param)
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIFczCgS3BGBeGAbwFgAoGCmAIgEMqAuGAMzQ2zAAoRHoAnTMAHMAlEV4BTKCl5hqAQSoBfADRlK1AEYNmrLOC6MwKOBvG9RhCVJnUAQkrKKA3GTICoZpjWDiYcomqUUAgADuKMtFSBFCE0vDRwPFD8Qo5uYB68Xj4wtgHkQaHhmlEFMXEJhsamvGmkZCzoerKCkgCSUByYjP4APrkW0TAQAO6YUMAAFjBdAHTBYYNl6jDANBC+kYxW0rKIqE3sEADamPNFALpzsfFwwkPqaxsl25K78Mi6R6fnYVdnNwS92WikcQA)

Or use a type assertion to just make things work:

```
function getIt(i: A | B) {
    const p = i.param;
    const f = myFunctions[i.type];
    return f(p as never); 
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIFczCgS3BGBeGAbwFgAoGCmAIgEMqAuGAMzQ2zAAoRHoAnTMAHMAlEV4BTKCl5hqAQSoBfADRlK1AEYNmrLOC6MwKOBvG9RhCVJnUAQkrKKA3GTICoZpjWDiYcomqUUAgADuKMtFSBFCE0vDRwPFD8Qo5uYB68Xj4wtgHkQaHhmlEFMXEJhsamvGmkZCzoerKCkgCSUByYjP4APrkW0TCgkLAh+DCYAHSx8XAuZcM4sEwTiKhN7BAA2tPBYQC6C+pW0rJMHOM0uGDiAG5mwk4wjkA)

Comment: I see: of course the union of `((o: string) => string) | ((o: number) => string)` is `never` interesting!

Comment: Still: Is there a type-safe way to solve my initial problem: Select the handler based on the property in an object? (With as few redundancies as possible?)

Comment: @htho `((o: string) => string) | ((o: number) => string)` is not simplified to `never` but it does end up as `(o: never) => string` when you try to call it. There is no type safe way to do it

Comment: thats what I meant (but not what I wrote) ;)